# How to stop LastPass on localhost?

Tags: lastpass

How to stop LastPass on localhost, I have tried the following using never urls:

[image]

Comment: Either uninstall it, or otherwise turn off syncing between machines using last pass

Comment: i got rid of it from brave thx,

Answer (score 8):

From: [this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lastpass/comments/xde8wh/help_disable_lastpass_for_localhostport/)

Lastpass Account | Settings | Never URLS

1. Click Add
2. Add an entry localhost/* as a "Never Do Anything"

If this doesn't work, try variations such as localhost*